# Scalar subquery produced more than one element - Standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

My query failed and showed the message "Scalar subquery produced more than one element"

```
  SELECT 
       EXTRACT (DATE FROM timestamp) AS Date
       ,jsonPayload.request.headers.origin AS URL
       ,jsonPayload.response.body.json.data.country.key AS Country
       ,(SELECT A.name FROM `pms_table_request_log.partners_request_log_*`, 
       UNNEST(jsonPayload.response.body.data.rows) AS A) AS Partner
       ,AVG((SELECT B.rating 
  FROM 
    `pms_table_request_log.partners_request_log_*`, 
     UNNEST(jsonPayload.response.body.data.rows) AS B)) AS Rating
    ,COUNT (*) AS Impression
    FROM 
       `pms_table_request_log.partners_request_log_*`
    GROUP BY 
        Date,URL,Country,Partner
    ORDER BY 
        Impression DESC;
```

Please guide what have I done wrong

Answer (score 2):

Your sub-query is resulting not in one element but in more than one element. BQ doesn't know what to do with more than one element when there is just room for one.

You can either feed the results into an array, which itself then again is only one element.
You can aggregate or restrict the output of your sub-query.
E.g.

```
(SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT A.name) FROM `pms_table_request_log.partners_request_log_*`, 
       UNNEST(jsonPayload.response.body.data.rows) AS A) AS Partner
```

or

```
(SELECT AVG(B.rating) 
  FROM 
    `pms_table_request_log.partners_request_log_*`, 
     UNNEST(jsonPayload.response.body.data.rows) AS B)) AS Rating
```

as aggregation examples.

For limiting:

```
(SELECT A.name FROM `pms_table_request_log.partners_request_log_*`, 
       UNNEST(jsonPayload.response.body.data.rows) AS A LIMIT 1) AS Partner
```

The right choice depends on the meaning of your data, though. Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I have managed to do it in a slightly different way.

SELECT
EXTRACT (DATE FROM timestamp) AS DATE
,A.name
,jsonPayload.request.headers.origin AS URL
,jsonPayload.response.body.data.country.key AS Country
,AVG(A.rating) AS Rating
,COUNT (*) AS Impression
FROM `pms_table_request_log.partners_request_log_*`, UNNEST(jsonPayload.response.body.data.rows) AS A 
GROUP BY
timestamp
,name
,URL
,Country
ORDER BY Impression DESC;

Comment: Sure, if you actually need non-aggregated values from the data, flattening would be the way to go. But my answer refers to the question you had.